# SQLite app gives AccessViolation on new SQLiteConnection Windows 10 v 20H2

Tags: windows, sqlite, c#-4.0

Sqlite crashes on SqliteConnecion

I have an application that uses Sqlite. I has been working perfectly for a couple of year.
I'm using Nuget System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.113.7
I tried to run it and i get this exception.

> System.AccessViolationException   HResult=0x80004003
> Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
> indication that other memory is corrupt.   Source=   StackTrace:

The exception occurs in the

```
public static string DbFile
{
    get { return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Foo\\Bar" + "\\Order.db"; }
}

public static SQLiteConnection OrderDbConnection()
{
    try
    {
        var db = $"Data Source={DbFile};Version=3;";
        return new SQLiteConnection(db);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var m = ex.Message;
        throw;
    }
}
```

on the line `return new SQLiteConnection(db);`

I'm using

- Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.35

  .NET Framework 4.7.2

  Edition  Windows 10 Pro

  Version  20H2

  Installed on ‎2020-‎11-‎05

  OS build 19042.928

  Experience   Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

I just tried the application on windows 10 version **1909** and there it **works**!

Has anyone any idea on what could be wrong?

EDIT: Add Exception from Event Viewer

> Application: DCMatrix.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
> The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
> Info: System.AccessViolationException    at
> System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConfigOpsEnum)
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized()    at
> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize(System.String)    at
> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(System.String, Boolean)
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(System.String)    at
> AbortedOrderDatabase.SqLiteBaseRepository.OrderDbConnection()    at
> AbortedOrderDatabase.SqLiteOrderRepository.IsOrderDone(System.String)
> at DCMatrix.Workflow.IsOrderDone(System.String)    at
> DCMatrix.Workflow.GetOrder(System.String, Boolean ByRef, Boolean
> ByRef)    at DCMatrix.ViewMainWindow.DoLoadDataCommand()    at
> DCMatrix.ViewMainWindow.<get_LoadDataCommand>b__21_1(System.Object)
> at DCMatrix.RelayCommand.Execute(System.Object)    at
> System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.TranslateInput(System.Windows.IInputElement,
> System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.OnKeyDownThunk(System.Object,
> System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs)    at
> System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate,
> System.Object)    at
> System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate,
> System.Object)    at
> System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object,
> System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)    at
> System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object,
> System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
> System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
> at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs,
> Boolean)    at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
> at
> System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
> at
> System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
> at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr,
> System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32,
> System.Windows.Input.RawKeyboardActions, Int32, Boolean, Boolean,
> Int32)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
> ByRef, Boolean ByRef)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
> ByRef, System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(System.Object)
> at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
> System.Object, Int32)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
> System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
> System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
> System.Delegate, System.Object)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
> ByRef, Boolean ByRef)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource+WeakEventPreprocessMessage.OnPreprocessMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
> ByRef, Boolean ByRef)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
> ByRef)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
> at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
> at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)    at
> System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)    at
> System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)    at
> System.Windows.Application.Run()    at DCMatrix.App.Main()

EDIT 2 Exception and Stack Trace

> System.AccessViolationException   HResult=0x80004003
> Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
> indication that other memory is corrupt.   Source=   StackTrace:
>
> "   at
> System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(SQLiteConfigOpsEnum
> op)    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized()    at
> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize(String className)    at
> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString,
> Boolean parseViaFramework)    at
> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
> at AbortedOrderDatabase.SqLiteBaseRepository.OrderDbConnection() in
> E:\Users\ame\source\repos\Seco
> Tools\DCMatrix\OrderDatabase\SqLiteBaseRepository.cs:line 23"

EDIT 3 Enabled Native Code Debugging

> Exception thrown at 0x776388E3 (ntdll.dll) in DCMatrix.exe:
> 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0044005C. occurred
>
> System.AccessViolationException   HResult=0x80004003
> Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
> indication that other memory is corrupt.   Source=   StackTrace:
>
> "   at
> System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(SQLiteConfigOpsEnum
> op)    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized()    at
> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize(String className)    at
> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString,
> Boolean parseViaFramework)    at
> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
> at AbortedOrderDatabase.SqLiteBaseRepository.OrderDbConnection() in
> E:\Users\ame\source\repos\Seco
> Tools\DCMatrix\OrderDatabase\SqLiteBaseRepository.cs:line 23    at
> AbortedOrderDatabase.SqLiteOrderRepository.IsOrderDone(String mo) in
> E:\Users\ame\source\repos\Seco
> Tools\DCMatrix\OrderDatabase\SqLiteOrderRepository.cs:line 57    at
> DCMatrix.Workflow.IsOrderDone(String mo) in
> E:\Users\ame\source\repos\Seco
> Tools\DCMatrix\DCMarker\Workflow.cs:line 977    at
> DCMatrix.Workflow.GetOrder(String tvnr, Boolean& isAbortedOrder,
> Boolean& isOrderDone) in E:\Users\ame\source\repos\Seco
> Tools\DCMatrix\DCMarker\Workflow.cs:line 920    at
> DCMatrix.ViewMainWindow.DoLoadDataCommand() in
> E:\Users\ame\source\repos\Seco
> Tools\DCMatrix\DCMarker\CommandMainWindow.cs:line 244    at
> DCMatrix.ViewMainWindow.<get_LoadDataCommand>b__21_1(Object p) in
> E:\Users\ame\source\repos\Seco
> Tools\DCMatrix\DCMarker\CommandMainWindow.cs:line 122    at
> DCMatrix.RelayCommand.Execute(Object parameter) in
> E:\Users\ame\source\repos\Seco
> Tools\DCMatrix\DCMarker\RelayCommand.cs:line 34    at
> System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.TranslateInput(IInputElement
> targetElement, InputEventArgs inputEventArgs)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.OnKeyDownThunk(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
> genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
> System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
> target)    at
> System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
> RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
> System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
> RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
> RoutedEventArgs args)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
> trusted)    at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
> at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs
> input)    at
> System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
> inputReport)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr
> hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawKeyboardActions actions,
> Int32 scanCode, Boolean isExtendedKey, Boolean isSystemKey, Int32
> virtualKey)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(MSG&
> msg, Boolean& handled)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(MSG&
> msg, ModifierKeys modifiers)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(Object param)
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
> callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
> Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
> at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
> priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
> numArgs)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority
> priority, Delegate method, Object arg)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(MSG& msg,
> Boolean& handled)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.WeakEventPreprocessMessage.OnPreprocessMessage(MSG&
> msg, Boolean& handled)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.ThreadMessageEventHandler.Invoke(MSG& msg,
> Boolean& handled)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(MSG&
> msg)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
> frame)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
> at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)    at
> System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    at
> System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)    at
> System.Windows.Application.Run()    at DCMatrix.App.Main()"

Comment: I'm using the Nuget System.Data.Sqlite.Core

Comment: Please show the stack trace at the point of the access violation.

Comment: The stack trace in VS is just what I already have show. I added the Stack trace from Event Viewer

Comment: I'm not asking about the message the .NET framework clobbers together. I was asking about the *full* call stack, including the native frames. A debugger will get you that, when configured to break whenever an SEH exception is triggered.

Comment: I selected all exception the where shown when i searched for SEH
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
ReleasesrHandleFailed.
The application just crashed with no error....

I then selected all exception in
C++ Exceptions
Common Language Runtime Exception
Win32 Exception
Now i got the exception I have added to my question

Comment: SQLite is a native, unmanaged library, but there aren't any native frames in the call stack. You'll will need to [enable mixed mode debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode#enable-mixed-mode-debugging-for-a-managed-calling-app) to get managed and **native** frames in the call stack.

Comment: I have enabled mixed mode debugging according to your link. I get a new exception 
Exception thrown at 0x776388E3 (ntdll.dll) in DCMatrix.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0044005C. occurred
but the stack trace is the same as before...

I have just tested to compile the solution for x64 and it seems like it works. Needs a lot more testing, but...